# C# - Using method from a Python file

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, python.net

I have two files, a regular python (.py) file and a visual studio C# file (.cs). I want to use a function in the python file which returns a string and use that string in the C# file.

Basically:

```
#This is the Python file!
def pythonString():
   return "Some String"
```

and

```
//This is the C# file!
namespace VideoLearning
{
    string whatever = pythonString(); // This is from the Python file.
}
```

How can I sort of link these two files together? Thanks.

Comment: It's not easy. You can use IronPython to create a .NEt compatible object, which you can then consume from your C# project: http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#declaring-net-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out IronPython! :)

Good declaration: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2009/10/25/running-ironpython-scripts-from-a-c-4-0-program/

Hope this helps, it's pretty ez ;)

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("Test.py");
test.pythonString(); //python-function to execute
```

just replace "pythonString()" with your function (already did this).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try pythonnet:

[python4.net](http://www.python4.net)